# Dropbox Docker Container not Syncing

Tags: docker, dropbox

I'm using the [janeczku/dropbox/](https://hub.docker.com/r/janeczku/dropbox/) to attempt syncing a data volume with a dropbox account.

Dropbox says that the daemon is connected and the logs from Docker also indicate that it is:

```
Please visit https://www.dropbox.com/cli_link_nonce?nonce=6d8e5915bf6fec325d220309dffc8ae5 to link this device.
This computer is now linked to Dropbox. Welcome ...
```

However the files are not syncing.  Any ideas on how to debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Analysis

It was not syncing because the Dropbox daemon was not current (It is supposed to keep itself current automatically, and I think it does with the latest image).  I found this out by running:

```
docker exec -t -i dropbox dropbox status
```

### Solution

I stopped the Dropbox container.

```
docker stop dropbox
```

Deleted it:

```
docker rm dropbox
```

Deleted the image

```
docker rmi janeczku/dropbox
```

Pulled the latest image:

```
docker pull janeczku/dropbox
```

Followed the instructions that come with the image again, and now they work.  Since I'm backing up files created by root I also had to set the UID and GID to 0.